# The Heat Equation in Brezis' book

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, heat-equation

I am reading the heat equation in *Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces, and Partial Differential Equations* by Haim Brezis, and having some concerns about the proof, whose screenshot is as attached below.

1. The notation $u\in L^2 (0, \infty; H^1_0(\Omega))$

   I can't find the definition of the notation in the book, but I believe it means $$ \int_0^\infty \left\Vert u(t) \right\Vert ^2 _{H^1_0(\Omega)} 
    dt < \infty$$ On $H^1_0(\Omega)$, $\left\Vert \nabla u(t) \right\Vert _{L^2(\Omega)} $ and $\left\Vert u(t) \right\Vert _{H^1(\Omega)} $ are equivalent norms by Poincare inequality.
2. *The boundary condition has been incorporated in the definition of the domain of A.*

   I think the key is $H_0^1(\Omega)$ since for a function $g\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ that admits a continuous representative, $g$ vanishes on the boundary. From the definition of domain $D(A) = H^2(\Omega) \cap H^1_0(\Omega)$, does it imply $g\in D(A)$ has a continuous representative? I believe the answer is no.
3. $D(A^l) = \{g\in H^{2l}(\Omega); g = \Delta g = ... = \Delta^{l-1}g = 0 \text{ on the boundary} \}$

   I can see $D(A^l) \subset H^{2l}(\Omega)$. The argument ($l = 2$ as an example) goes as follows.

   $$ g \in D(A^2) \Rightarrow g \in D(A), - \Delta g \in D(A) \Rightarrow - \Delta g + g \in H^2(\Omega) \Rightarrow g \in H^4(\Omega)$$

   The last arrow follows from a regularity theorem (Theorem 9.25). But again, $g\in D(A^l)$ may not have a continuous representative (at least when $l$ is not sufficiently large) so how to see $g = \Delta g =... = 0$ on the boundary?
4. $u\in C^k((0,\infty); C^k(\bar \Omega))$ for all k

   My understanding is that $u$ as a function from $(0,\infty)$ to $C^k(\bar \Omega)$ is a $C^k$ function, and for each fixed $t_1$, $u(t_1)$ is a $C^k$ function on $\bar \Omega$. How do we conclude from here that $u(x,t): \Omega \times (0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ is $C^k$? The differentiability of $u\in C^k((0,\infty); C^k(\bar \Omega))$ uses the Banach space topology while the partial derivative $u_t(x,t)$ in $t$ is formulated in the usual sense.

   More specifically, let $[U(t)](x)$ be the map viewed as $(0,\infty)$ to $C^k(\bar \Omega)$ and $u(x,t)$ be the one viewed as $\Omega \times (0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$, how to show that $u_t(x,t) = d[U(t)](x)/dt $?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

(Update)

I consulted Evan's PDE book, and my own answers (at least how I convinced myself) go as follows.

- For point 1, yes. More generally, $u\in L^p(0,\infty; X)$ for a Banach space $X$ means $$ \int_0^\infty \left\Vert u(t) \right\Vert ^ p _X dt < \infty $$
- For point 2 & 3, we need the fact that $$ u \in H^1_0 (\Omega) \iff u = 0 \text{ on the boundary}$$To justify the statement (since $u$ can differ from a set of measure zero and the boundary has measure zero), we probably need the theory of trace. Anyways, in Brezis' book, only a special case is proven (when $u$ has a continuous representative, see Theorem 9.17), and the trace operator is briefly mentioned in page 315.
- I think I came up with a solution for point 4.

  Let $u(x,t) = [U(t)](x)$. Fix a point $x_0 \in \Omega$.
  $$(\frac{d[U(t)]}{dt}) (x_0) = (\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{U(t+h)-U(t)}{h})(x_0) = \lim_{h\to 0}\frac{[U(t+h)](x_0)-[U(t)](x_0)}{h} = u_t(x_0,t)$$
  since the continuity of evaluation at $x_0$ allows us to pass through the limit.

If there is any mistake or there is a better way/answer for my questions, please let me know. Anyways I hope this post helps those who only read Brezis' book like me.

Comment: Thank you for putting so much effort into your question. Unfortunately I am not yet experienced enough in functional analysis to answer it.